# Apache POI: getNumMergedRegions

Tags: java, apache-poi

I use `sheet.getNumMergedRegions()` and I have code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
                CellRangeAddress merge = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
                System.out.println("Number: " + i);
                System.out.println("first column: " + merge.getFirstColumn() + " last column " + merge.getLastColumn());
                System.out.println("first row: " + merge.getFirstRow() + " last row " + merge.getLastRow());
                System.out.println("==============");
                System.out.println();
            }
```

I have result:

```
Number: 0
first column: 33 last column 35
first row: 0 last row 0
==============

Number: 1
first column: 10 last column 11
first row: 1 last row 1
==============

Number: 2
first column: 20 last column 23
first row: 1 last row 1
==============

Number: 3
first column: 20 last column 23
first row: 0 last row 0
==============
```

How is determined the order of in result? Why firstly is Number 0 instead of Number 3?

Answer (score 3):

The merged regions are stored inside an `ArrayList` in the `MergedCellsTable` class.

Therefore, they are stored in the same order as you add the regions to the `Sheet`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Dump");
   sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,1,2,3));
   sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,0,0));
   sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,1,2,2));
   sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(3,3,3,3));

   //Output 
   System.out.println("num merged reagons: "+ sheet.getNumMergedRegions());
   for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
      CellRangeAddress merge = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
      System.out.println("Number:" + i+ " " + merge.getFirstRow() + " " + merge.getLastRow()+  " " + merge.getFirstColumn() + " " + merge.getLastColumn());
   }
}
```

leads to

> Num merged Regions: 4
>   Number:0 0 1 2 3
>   Number:1 0 0 0 0
>   Number:2 0 1 2 2
>   Number:3 3 3 3 3

which is analog to the order in which I added the four regions to the sheet.